# Is multiple queries or LEFT JOIN faster?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
TABLE tb1
id int(11)
col1 int(11)
PRIMARY (id)

TABLE tb2
id int(11)
col2 int(11)
tb1_id int(11)
PRIMARY (id)
INDEX (tb1_id)
UNIQUE (col2, tb1_id)
```

I am trying to get the rows in `tb1` where `col1 = 123`,

and then check if there is a unique pair `[col2=456, tb1_id=<tb1 id>]` in `tb2`.

---

I could 2 selects:

```
SELECT tb1.*
FRoM tb1
WHERE tb1.col1 = 123

foreach <tb1 id> in results
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tb2
    WHERE tb2.col2 = 456 AND tb2.tb1_id = <tb1 id>
```

Or use a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT tb1.*, COUNT(tb2.id)
FROM tb1
LEFT JOIN tb2 ON tb2.tb1_id = tb1.id
WHERE tb1.col1 = 123 AND tb2.col2 = 456
GROUP BY tb1.id
```

which is faster?

Comment: This is highly dependent on a lot of things. Have you measured either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joins are faster, please use **EXPLAIN** keyword before query start, you will come to know the statistics in terms of time and other factor of how mysql executes query against database.

e.g.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT tb1.*, COUNT(tb2.id)
FROM tb1
LEFT JOIN tb2 ON tb2.tb1_id = tb1.id
WHERE tb1.col1 = 123 AND tb2.col2 = 456
GROUP BY tb1.id
```

Thanks
Amit